# LTE- modem Huawei E3372 on Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04

I can not connect LTE- modem Huawei E3372 on Ubuntu 14.04.3. The system identifies it as a CD. Do not create a new connection in Network Manager. Please write as detailed as possible , how to connect a modem, because I have a new Ubuntu user. Many thanks!